# Can I sell rare ancient artifacts?

Tags: horizon-zero-dawn

I've just begun encountering ancient ruins, and finding artifacts ranging in value from common to rare.  In the Merchant menu for these resources, it describes them as "Used for selling for metal shards."

I'm wondering if there's a hidden reason to keep these items, or if I should sell them as soon as I can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If 'Selling for metal shards' is the only thing listed in the description then you can safely sell them as they don't have any other use. The rarity value just affects how much they are worth.

Things that can be used will either be in the Resources listed with other things in the description (such as 'crafting') or in the Special Items list.

Comment: Great!  I was afraid there might be some hidden trophy or other secret achievment based on keeping rare items.

Answer (score -3):

Certain artifacts are extremely helpful in the game, but you should be fine selling a few.

Comment: This would be better if you explained what was helpful and what wasn’t.